# What is wrong with my simple Clojure gen-class script?

Tags: clojure, gen-class

I'm trying to learn how to use `gen-class` in Clojure. I've started with this simple script:

```
(gen-class :name MyClass :prefix MyClass-)

(defn MyClass-toString[this] "This Is My Class")

(println (MyClass.))
```

When I try to run it I get

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: MyClass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [AOT compilation](http://clojure.org/compilation) for `gen-class`.

Comment: That did it! I put the class in a separate file and called `compile` on that file, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

edit, Also, check that the main class name matches the one defined in the lein project file.

Usually you put in the (ns) header of the clj file.

```
(ns my.namespace
  (:gen-class))
```

Here's some examples

```
(gen-class
    :name "some.package.RefMap"
    :implements [java.util.Map]
    :state "state"
    :init "init"
    :constructors {[] []}
    :prefix "ref-map-")
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this as a script with `clj`, without Leiningen, in the default namespace. I couldn't get `gen-class` to work in a lein project, so I'm trying to run the simplest thing possible - one class, no namespace, no state, no inheritance. And this has nothing to do with the main class I'm trying to run - because the main class is not named `MyClass` and I'm not trying to run a class named `MyClass`(only to construct it) - and that's the class the Exception is talking about.

Comment: With or without lein, check that the class name matches the filename.clj. Just remember to replace '-' with '_'.

Comment: Also, please refer to the examples at http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-class